# JavaCV on android ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, opencv, javacv, computer-vision

I'v been trying to run JavaCV code on an Android project.
This code worked for me while running on Windows 7 (using Eclipse).

i searched for the errors i got and tried setting everything up as described in this forum answers and others but still no luck.

i created a libs folder with the *.Jar files and included them in my build path.
i also added the *.so files to the libs\armeabi folder

i will appreciate your prompt replay in the matter.

below are all the specifics.

libs folder:

```
 <DIR>        .
 <DIR>          ..
 <DIR>          armeabi
 <DIR>          armeabi-v7a
         83,949 javacpp.jar
      1,239,034 javacv-macosx-x86_64.jar
        932,050 javacv-windows-x86.jar
      1,211,623 javacv-windows-x86_64.jar
        955,900 javacv.jar

'armeabi' folder:

7,306,044 libavcodec.so
   40,484 libavdevice.so
  578,872 libavfilter.so
1,169,460 libavformat.so
  141,516 libavutil.so
  394,443 libjniARToolKitPlus.so
  418,079 libjniavcodec.so
   95,819 libjniavdevice.so
  218,655 libjniavfilter.so
  225,831 libjniavformat.so
  153,427 libjniavutil.so
  112,051 libjnicvkernels.so
  125,263 libjniopencv_calib3d.so
  613,075 libjniopencv_contrib.so
  545,215 libjniopencv_core.so
  238,119 libjniopencv_features2d.so
  101,479 libjniopencv_flann.so
   57,979 libjniopencv_highgui.so
  249,339 libjniopencv_imgproc.so
1,017,267 libjniopencv_legacy.so
  663,071 libjniopencv_ml.so
   86,719 libjniopencv_nonfree.so
  241,027 libjniopencv_objdetect.so
   39,579 libjniopencv_photo.so
  680,443 libjniopencv_stitching.so
  110,255 libjniopencv_video.so
  167,499 libjniopencv_videostab.so
   87,503 libjnipostproc.so
   91,627 libjniswresample.so
  108,119 libjniswscale.so
  957,220 libopencv_calib3d.so
1,063,888 libopencv_contrib.so
2,349,724 libopencv_core.so
  880,336 libopencv_features2d.so
  706,228 libopencv_flann.so
1,146,792 libopencv_highgui.so
1,990,768 libopencv_imgproc.so
1,415,324 libopencv_legacy.so
  880,584 libopencv_ml.so
  458,764 libopencv_nonfree.so
  422,580 libopencv_objdetect.so
   68,080 libopencv_photo.so
  769,728 libopencv_stitching.so
  902,676 libopencv_ts.so
  203,904 libopencv_video.so
  560,688 libopencv_videostab.so
   89,080 libpostproc.so
   65,572 libswresample.so
  204,020 libswscale.so


The error log file:


08-16 15:12:56.030: E/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 942 (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000e
08-16 15:12:56.030: I/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find method java.awt.color.ColorSpace.getInstance, referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve static method 13250: Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;.getInstance (I)Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0033
08-16 15:12:56.030: E/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 944 (Ljava/awt/image/ComponentColorModel;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0052
08-16 15:12:56.030: E/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 942 (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0094
08-16 15:12:56.030: E/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 942 (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x00b7
08-16 15:12:56.030: I/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find method java.awt.color.ColorSpace.getInstance, referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve static method 13250: Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;.getInstance (I)Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00c6
08-16 15:12:56.030: I/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find method java.awt.color.ColorSpace.getInstance, referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve static method 13250: Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;.getInstance (I)Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00de
08-16 15:12:56.030: E/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 944 (Ljava/awt/image/ComponentColorModel;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x00fc
08-16 15:12:56.030: E/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 944 (Ljava/awt/image/ComponentColorModel;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x012e
08-16 15:12:56.030: E/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 944 (Ljava/awt/image/ComponentColorModel;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0160
08-16 15:12:56.030: E/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 944 (Ljava/awt/image/ComponentColorModel;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0191
08-16 15:12:56.030: E/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 944 (Ljava/awt/image/ComponentColorModel;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x01c2
08-16 15:12:56.030: E/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 942 (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x01f9
08-16 15:12:56.030: E/dalvikvm(3801): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
08-16 15:12:56.030: W/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 942 (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;) in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0077
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x0010-001e in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x0036-0036 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x0054-0076 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x0079-0083 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x0096-00b2 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x00b9-00b9 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x00c9-00c9 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x00e1-00e1 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x00fe-0124 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x0130-0156 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x0162-0188 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x0193-01b9 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x01c4-01ea in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.030: D/dalvikvm(3801): VFY: dead code 0x01fb-0205 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage (DZLjava/awt/color/ColorSpace;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;
08-16 15:12:56.035: I/dalvikvm(3801): DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x0ef1 at 0xa2 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.copyFrom
08-16 15:12:56.035: I/dalvikvm(3801): DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x0ef1 at 0x88 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.copyTo
08-16 15:12:56.045: I/dalvikvm(3801): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
08-16 15:12:56.105: D/dalvikvm(3801): GC_CONCURRENT freed 243K, 48% free 2948K/5639K, external 8639K/9382K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-16 15:12:56.185: D/dalvikvm(3801): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.zdm.picabus/lib/libopencv_core.so 0x4051c668
08-16 15:12:56.190: D/dalvikvm(3801): Added shared lib /data/data/com.zdm.picabus/lib/libopencv_core.so 0x4051c668
08-16 15:12:56.190: D/dalvikvm(3801): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.zdm.picabus/lib/libopencv_core.so 0x4051c668, skipping init
08-16 15:12:56.190: W/dalvikvm(3801): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core;
08-16 15:12:56.190: W/dalvikvm(3801): Exception Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown while initializing Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$CvArr;
08-16 15:12:56.190: D/AndroidRuntime(3801): Shutting down VM
08-16 15:12:56.190: W/dalvikvm(3801): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at com.zdm.picabus.imageprocessing.costumizeImg.processImage(costumizeImg.java:22)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at com.zdm.picabus.cameraservices.CameraActivity.onActivityResult(CameraActivity.java:33)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3934)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2111)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:314)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:294)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:156)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     ... 18 more
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jniopencv_core: findLibrary returned null
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:367)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:294)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:129)
08-16 15:12:56.195: E/AndroidRuntime(3801):     ... 23 more"
```

Comment: The Eclipse Android plug-in doesn't really work all that well. Android itself also has a few bugs in its caching mechanism, so try to uninstall everything and recreate all your project files from scratch. Does that fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your res folder. try to replicate everything from the opencv code sample you have. Seems it fails to load images. Alternatively, you could Clean your project (in menu go to Project>Clean) or use a real phone instead of the emulator. See if any option will resolve your error.